# Loop the contents of a JSON array object

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I am new to Vb.net. Having a JSON string as given below, I tries to deserialize the JSON into an Object using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()`.
I am trying to loop values inside the **`Content`** object in the given JSON to fetch its values.
I tried using a `for` loop, but I'm not able to get the exact values.

```
  Dim result As String = {
  "status": "0001",
  "Result": {
    "IsError": "0",
    "Data": {
      "Type": "a",
      "Header": [
        "v1",
        "v2",
        "v3",
        "v4",
        "v5"
      ],
      "Content": [
        [
          "001",
          "Raj",
          "1",
          "N",
          ""
        ],
        [
          "002",
          "Vignesh",
          "1",
          "N",
          ""
        ],
        [
          "778",
          "Ramesh",
          "1",
          "N",
          ""
        ],
        [
          "792",
          "Suresh",
          "1",
          "N",
          ""
        ],
        [
          "703",
          "Karthick",
          "1",
          "N",
          ""
        ],
        [
          "1247",
          "Ram",
          "1",
          "N",
          ""
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

```
Dim jsonResult2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(result)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to deserialize the Content array, you can parse the JSON with `JToken.Parse()`, then deserialize to a `List(Of String())` that section only.

```
Dim jsonResult = JToken.Parse(result)
Dim content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of String()))(
    jsonResult("Result")("Data")("Content").ToString()
)
```

Or, you could use a class Model to deserialize the whole JSON, then access each object as a standard .Net Property value.

```
Public Class StatusResultsRoot
    <JsonProperty("status")>
    Public Property Status As String
    Public Property Result As Result
End Class

Public Partial Class Result
    Public Property IsError As String
    Public Property Data As Data
End Class

Public Partial Class Data
    <JsonProperty("Type")>
    Public Property DataType As String
    Public Property Header As List(Of String)
    Public Property Content As List(Of String())
End Class

'[...]

Dim statusResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of StatusResultsRoot)(result)
```

The `Content` List is then

```
Dim content As List(Of String()) = statusResult.Result.Data.Content

' Loop the List of String(), print the combined array of strings
For Each stringArray As String() In content
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", stringArray))
Next
```

---

In case you actually want to *embed* a JSON as a string, you can use an [XML element literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/xml/xml-literals-overview), defining an [XElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?) by enclosing the JSON with <`node> ... </node>` markers.
You can then paste in the JSON as is (no need to double the double-quotes).
The JSON is then the string representation of the first node of the XElement: i.e., `[XElement].FirstNode.ToString()`. For example:

```
Dim xResult = <json> {
    "status":  "0001",
    "Result": {
        "IsError": "0",
        "Data": {
            ' [... other content ...]
        }
    }
} </json>

Dim json As String = xResult.FirstNode.ToString()
```

You cannot do this in C#.

Answer (score 0):

A string in VB must begin and end with a ".

The inner double quotes should be replaced with "".

So a proper string(when assigning it in code) would look like:

```
Dim result as string = "{
""status"": ""0001"",
...
}
"
```

Comment: There's no need. You can add an XElement marker: `Dim result = <json> { All the rest } </json>`. But that's an example of the actual JSON (I hope :)

Comment: That would surely be the preferred way. I don't have much experience with JSONs. Anyway, just pointing out that the string declaration in the question is wrong.